# Embed Google Analytics existing dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In the Google Analytics console I can easily create charts and add them to dashboards. But how can I display those charts or dashboards on a 3rd party website?

I've seen the [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/), but it looks like the definition of the reports is always in the Javascript. Is it not possible to say something like *display the dashboard that I already created which name/id is XYZ*?

Or is there a way, when creating a report in Google Analytics, to get its definition so that I can easily use it? I saw [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) but it doesn't help.

Comment: Check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com  - we specialize in the creation of dashboards that can be embedded into 3rd party sites.  We also have a tool where you can submit a GA dashboard and we will create it on your account for you.  Our agency version is suited for sites that need to display data for different profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not take the Google Analytics dashboard and display it on another website.

The best option there is to date is the [Embedded API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) which you mentioned. Although it has its limitations. The Embedded API is designed to display a specific users Google Analytics Dashboard who ever is logged in.  If you are trying to share the information from your account with other users it wont work unless they also have access to your Google Analytics account.

The Query Explorer shows you what the [google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) is capable of. You can develop your own tool to show this information to your users.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, seeing that there were several commercial offering to help you display dashboards or graphs on your site...In my use case, there's only one GA accounts to display, so there's no issue with the embedded API.

Comment: yes but If I come to your site its going to display my google analytics data not yours.  It connects to the account of the user who is logged in.

Comment: @DalmTo: yes indeed, but in my case that's not an issue.